# Python regex expression for weight values that may or may not contain decimals?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm learning regex and I'm hoping to match a sequence that represents this:

[zero or more numbers][possibly a decimal][zero or more numbers][fixed character]

In this case, the fixed character is 'g'. No decimal is fine as well

Hoping to match:

```
    .5g
    0.5g
    1.5g
    1.75g
    3g
    10g
```

I've tried `r'(\d*\.?\d?\d*?+g)'` But I've encountered a multiple repeat at position (x) error. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Play with this...https://regex101.com/r/ec72h9/1

Comment: `?+` doesn't work since `?` (1 or 0 of the preceding, preferably 1) and `+` (at least 1 of the preceding, preferably more) are both quantifiers. Drop the question mark and clean a little to get `r'\d*\.?\d+g'`.

Comment: That link is super helpful. Appreciate it!

Comment: Your description suggests that you wish to match a string consisting of a single character `g`. If that is your intent I suggest you add `g` to your list of desired matches, else revise your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simpler expression

```
r'(\d*\.?\d*g)'
```

This is simply the translation of your request into regex.